# Unknown option `--tail` when running `drush ws --tail`

Tags: 8, drush

I am using Drush version 9.0-dev-dev.

When I run `drush ws --tail`, I get the following error:

```
[error]  Unknown option: --tail.  See `drush help watchdog-show` for available options. To suppress this error, add the option --strict=0.
```

I've used this with all other versions of drush with no issues.

Comment: I have drush 9.0-dev and the sentence works fine

Comment: Same Problem here ...

-> see https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3414

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a known issue tracked and answered on [GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3414).

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the [linked issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3414).

> Some existing Drush commands were simplified in Drush 9. I think that
>   --tail would still be a welcome addition, if someone wanted to submit a PR.

But as of today the [pull request](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/3523) is still unmerged. Maybe you can reanimate it and provide some help.

Comment: As a dirty and quick workaround you can use: `watch -n2 drush ws`. This runs the drush command each 2 seconds, displaying the result. The effect is seeing the updated list of last entries on the watchdog.

Comment: For anyone arriving here much later, the command is now `drush wt` instead.